# Store BitmapFactory in my folder and later be able to retrieve it based on the name

Tags: java, android, image, imageview

My current code:

```
URL url = new URL("URL_I_USE_TO_RETRIEVE_A_PHOTO");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
```

I show this bitmap in a `imageview` and it works perfectly. However, to store some bandwidth, I want to store photos locally if such name exists. How can I store it and later check if such photo exists? I checked some answers here, but they don't deal with retrieving pictures later.

Comment: Take a look at this [Android training page](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the inputStream from the URL and store into a FileOutputStream. Later you could decode the bitmap again using FileInputStream.

example:

```
InputStream in= url.openConnection().getInputStream();
OutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(...);
IOUtils.copy(in,out);
in=new FileInputStream(...);
Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
```

Anyway, there are some libraries that do it for you, that include caching and many other features. You should also consider downsampling in case the images can be rather large (or have unspecified size).